# JasperReports font extension +~JF*****.tmp files

Tags: java, fonts, jboss, jasper-reports, tmp

I have a main application on a *JBoss* server who has inside standalone modules who work with *JasperReports*.

I need to use font extensions for my reports. After a lot of problems i did manage to make them work.

```
ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader( new URL[] {new URL("file:///app/jasper-fonts.jar")} );
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(cl);
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params);
```

My reports use the font from the extension. Everything seems fine.
**But...**
I have 1.200.000 reports to do. And because of the font extension i get some tmp files (+~JF*****.tmp) on my server on /tmp. 1 file has 700Kb, 700Kb*1.2mil = crash, so i can't keep them all.

It's there any solution to not save these? Or to delete them after generation?

Comment: see [Font.createFont leaves files in temp directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751673)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest caching and reusing the classloader across report executions.  That would help with performance as well, in addition to creating a single set of font temp files.