# How to add Fonts to Azure Web Application Java JVM for server side use

Tags: java, azure, fonts, garbage-collection, azure-web-app-service

How do I make my own custom fonts available to the JVM when deployed in Azure as a Web Application? (note - this is different than serving them back in an html page and configuring the proper MIME types. I'm applying fonts to an image generated using lucee and coldfusion.)

In the old world when we used a virtual machine, we would simply add the fonts to the system font folder and the JVM would have them available at run time. With Azure Web Applications, this folder is not accessible to me. We are running Java 8.

Things I thought should work, but don't seem to:

- using the JAVA_FONTS environment variable to specify a path to my custom fonts folder (with ttf files in it)
- Making Java calls to create and register the font within my web application. getLocalGraphicsEnvironment / CreateFont / RegisterFont (this registers the fonts, but the Garbage Collector thread chokes and crashes on the Disposer - crashing my JVM every few hours. Take the font loading out, and it runs smoooooth)

Now the fact they didn't work for me might be as simple as misunderstanding the exact syntax of the process.

How can I load my fonts in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add a key-value pair on the Application Settings blade that looked like this:

JAVA_OPTS

-Dsun.java2d.fontpath=D:\home\site\wwwroot\webapps\ROOT\App\include\fonts

That loaded the fonts properly. (My bug on Garbage Collection is still there, but the question of loading fonts has been solved)

Answer (score 0):

Base on what I found in this [document](http://www.securiteam.com/windowsntfocus/5UP0H0KDFU.html).

I think the main reason for your Garbage Collector thread crash is that the **CreateFont** method creates a large amount of **temporary files**.

**Solution:**

You could refer to the snippet of the code below replace the inputStream method.

```
String pathString = FontLoader.class.getResource("/font/xxx.ttf").getFile();
Font dynamicFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File(pathString));
```

You could also refer to the SO thread:[Font.createFont leaves files in temp directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751673/font-createfont-leaves-files-in-temp-directory).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I'm not seeing any signs of temp file build up.The createFont is only called on the first call to the app when it initializes - and even then with only 6 fonts.