# PDFBox not clean tmp files after convertToImage method

Tags: pdfbox

I use the PDFBox function, such as convertToImage, everything works fine, but PDFBox does not clear the temporary files after the conversion. In my system in the directory for temporary files "/tmp" there are many files such us +~JF132216249314633400.tmp, they are deleted only after restarting my application, but when the application continues to work, temporary files are not deleted.

PDFBox version - 1.8.15

when I use this

```
page.convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, 300)
```

the PDFbox library creates tmp files such as "+~JF132216249314633400.tmp"

my method:

```
def splitPdfToImages(file: File): List[File] = {
    val document = PDDocument.load(file)
    val pages = (for (i <- 0 until document.getNumberOfPages)
      yield document.getDocumentCatalog.getAllPages.get(i).asInstanceOf[PDPage]).toList
    val imgFiles = pages.zipWithIndex.map { case (page, i) =>
      val baos = IOUtils.createBAOS
      ImageIO.write(page.convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, 300), "jpg", baos)
      val bais = IOUtils.createBAIS(baos.toByteArray)
      try {
        val img = Image.fromStream(bais)
        implicit val writer = JpegWriter().withCompression(100)
        val tmpFile = File.createTempFile(s"""${file.getName.split("\\.").head}_$i""", file.getName.split("\\.").last)
        img.output(tmpFile)
      } finally {
        baos.close()
        bais.close()
      }
    }
    document.close()
    imgFiles
  }
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Isn't it you who is creating files in the temp directory? `File.createTempFile`

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I have successfully delete this files in the method above, because I know file name, but it is not the files that I need to delete. I need to delete files which created in `page.convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, 300)` I not know what file name is created and I can not to delete its.

Comment: Could you please look inside such a file with an editor like NOTEPAD++ and tell how it looks? I'm wondering whether it can be proven or disproven that this file is created by pdfbox.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr it look like this: `@BASEe]½FDSIGlÚÉ»ë(äGDEFÒêÕ¾\~GPOSÿ§¡ÜXGSUB#Iãµ4OS/2¼×òÈ`SVG Ôòû÷ÎÈ`cmapjÀg¾d5,cvt ¿qQH"fpgmY7OsgaspÿÿglyfÓiÙ]ñ¼headú7L6hhea3$hmtx1=ò(<loca÷ÄQl maxp4w¨ name¤»OHtpostæKf¼8Nprepú6ÀÄQBpÇ,ð_<õ èÑÁÇJÑÂ)»ÿ?þp$ ØþïXÿ?ÿ?r` [file example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d0kl2m7xfe4rdfb/%2B~JF2080168964847778678.tmp?dl=0)

Comment: GPOS, GDEF and GSUB indicates it is a font. Later there is certificate stuff, and then SVG stuff?! Might be this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751673/font-createfont-leaves-files-in-temp-directory

Comment: If you can, use 2.0.12, fonts are no longer handled by java, and rendering is much better. See the migration guide on the pdfbox website.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I added unnecessary fonts. but it did not help, temporary files are still not deleted by myself, I have to delete them with a separate service. I also noticed that I constantly reduce the free space on the hard disk of the server. only a full server reload returns the free space on the hard disk. but the weight / tmp folder is no more than 20 megabytes. I can not understand where free space is.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Unfortunately now there is no time for migration to "PDFbox" 2.0.12 - the project is in production and you need to make it fully working with those libraries that are.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "non-tradable fonts". From the rest of your comment this looks like there's something bigger going on, if space is getting lost and you don't know where. Btw your document.close() is not part of a `finally`. Also make sure you're using the latest version of whatever that language is and the latest java runtime.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr non-tradable fonts - fonts that are not enough for PDFbox. I can not update the PDFbox version at the moment because the project is very big and there are many depencies of PDFbox's methods inside the project. I think the PDFbox's developers will fix this issue in a newest 1.8.x versions. But the problem is still here. At the moment I work wit the small count of pdfs and the space is enough, but when the count os pdfs will increase the space will be not enough.

Comment: I am a PDFBox developer and we won't fix this issue because from what I see it is a java problem (see link from October 12). I just looked in the source code and I see a memory leak. However fixing these doesn't fix the problem, there are still JF files and it is fonts.

Comment: You can try with a snapshot: https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/1.8.17-SNAPSHOT/ I was able to delete most, but not all JF files while the program was running.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thanks, I will try it.